# SQLiteOpenHelper no response on query

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I try to make my app, it's kinda dictionary with training staff. But I'm stuck at this moment:
I need insert statistic of word (correct and incorrect answer), but all query finish with errors:

```
<code>E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.maxvek.myapplication, PID: 9088
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException:Index -1 requested,with a size of 1</code>
```

or something like this:

```
no response from DB
```

I tried make same query at sqliteonline and this work.

I just don't know what to do. I read some stuff and I think what I need some callback. But I'm new to java and can't even understand how to do it.

My class:

### DatabaseHelper

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,uk TEXT, en TEXT, ru TEXT, de TEXT, fr TEXT)");
sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_STAT_WORD + " (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,uk TEXT, en TEXT, ru TEXT, de TEXT, fr TEXT, cor INTEGER, incor INTEGER)");
...

public void insertStatWord(String word, String lang, Boolean answer) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select id from " + TABLE_NAME + " where " + lang + " = '" + word + "' limit(1)", null);
    String id = res.getString(0);
    if (answer) {
        Cursor update = db.rawQuery("update " + TABLE_STAT_WORD + " set cor = cor+1 WHERE " + lang + " = " + id, null);
        if (update == null) {
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(lang, id);
            contentValues.put("cor", 1);
            db.insert(TABLE_STAT_WORD, null, contentValues);
        }
    } else {
        Cursor update = db.rawQuery("update " + TABLE_STAT_WORD + " set incor = incor+1 WHERE " + lang + " = " + id, null);
        if (update == null) {
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(lang, id);
            contentValues.put("incor", 1);
            db.insert(TABLE_STAT_WORD, null, contentValues);
        }
    }
...
}
```

### DatabaseInstance

```
public class DatabaseInstance {
private static DatabaseInstance ourInstance = new DatabaseInstance();
private DatabaseHelper myDB;

private DatabaseInstance() {
}

public static DatabaseInstance getInstance() {
    return ourInstance;
}

public synchronized void init(Context context) {
    if (myDB == null) {
        myDB = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }
}

public DatabaseHelper getMyDB() {
    return myDB;
}
}
```

From this fragment I try call this method:

### TrainingFragment

```
private void statOfWord(String word, String lang, boolean answer) {
    DatabaseInstance.getInstance().getMyDB().insertStatWord(word, lang, answer);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cursor returned by this:

```
Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select id from " + TABLE_NAME + " where " + lang + " = '" + word + "' limit(1)", null);
```

may or may not contain 1 row, so you must check it:

```
String id = "";
if (res.moveToFirst()){
    id = res.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(0));
}
if (id.isEmpty())
    return;
```

**Also** in your code you need twice to execute update statements but you do it by executing the wrong method.  
The method `rawQuery()` is used to fetch data from a table by a `SELECT` statement and **not to update** data.  
Instead you must use the method `execSQL()` which does not return anything, like this:

```
db.execSQL("update " + TABLE_STAT_WORD + " set cor = cor + 1 WHERE " + lang + " = " + id);
```

and

```
db.execSQL("update " + TABLE_STAT_WORD + " set incor = incor + 1 WHERE " + lang + " = " + id);
```

Comment: ty dude, all working, your and @Prasanth realy help me.
About update, i try to do "Update or Insert", so basically it's 1 update, but ty for explaining this)

Comment: @MaXiM4Uk did you change to execSQL?

Comment: no, execSQL it's void, i need check if update was success, or i should check by executeUpdate() ?

Comment: actually i was wrong, i change code:
    db.execSQL("update " + TABLE_STAT_WORD + " set cor = cor + 1 WHERE " + lang + " = " + id);
                long update  = DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(db, "SELECT changes()", null);
                if (update == 0){
                    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                    contentValues.put(lang, id);
                    contentValues.put("cor", 1);
                    contentValues.put("incor", 0);
                    db.insert(TABLE_STAT_WORD, null, contentValues);
                }